# mixing simple present with present progressive

Tags: tense, present-tense

> The children sit on the sofa, watching TV. Their mom watches too.

Is it weird or normal to write "watches" in the example above when I have just used "watching"?

Comment: The children sit; the mother watches. Both simple present. Normal.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Bonus question: Should I add "it" between "watches" and "too" or is it OK as it is?

Comment: It's optional - not necessary. The context makes it clear.